# R count number of NA values for each row of a CSV

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the number of NA values for each row of a csv. How would I create a data frame containing the row name and count of NA values for that row?

Dataset -

```
#   KJIS10    TYDA40    CSDF32    ASDF67
#c1 52.12     NA        NA        67.23
#c2 NA        60.3      23.78     73.23
#c3 69.32     123.21    18.46     95.42
#c4 78.23     NA        94.36     107.43
#c5 89.15     47.98     36.18     38.54
#c6 90.45     NA        78.12     32.21
#c7 NA        67.2      NA        NA
```

What I've tried so far, I'm able to get the correct counts but it's not summarised.

```
#Created dataframe from CSV
df = as.data.frame(import)
missing = rowSums(is.na(df))
```

Data frame I'm trying to create -

```
#'c1    2
#'c2    1
#'c3    0
#'c4    1
#'c5    0
#'c6    1
#'c7    3
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(missing)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
result <- data.frame("rowmname"=rownames(df), "missing"=rowSums(is.na(df)))
result
```